# How to add icon to semantic ui dropdown?

Tags: c#, css, asp.net, vb.net, semantic-ui

On https://jsfiddle.net/u40uz1c4/4/, how can I add those icons to the dropdown?

I have ASP.NET dropdowns each with a list of items that I want to skin with the semantic dropdown. I want however svg images as icons for each item.

Reference: http://semantic-ui.com/modules/dropdown.html#/usage

```
<select name="gender" class="ui dropdown" id="select">
  <option value="">Gender</option>
  <option value="male">Male</option>
  <option value="female">Female</option>
</select>
<br />
<br />

<img src='http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/icons8/ios7/512/Users-User-Male-icon.png' style='width:20px;'>

<img src='http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/icons8/ios7/512/Users-User-Female-icon.png' style='width:20px;'>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cant do that by ASP.NET controller. You have to ctrate simple html markup, and than use the script for convert it to drop down list

Comment: That could be challenging. Currently those ASP.NET dropdowns have AutoPostback=True and also we have server-side aspx.vb code that programatically adds or removes certain dropdown items on some dropdowns according to the user's profile. Does anyone know the approach to handle all that and still have the semantic dropdown skin as well as our image icons on the dropdowns?

Comment: I dont know any way to do that. If it's important to you, you can use the html markup, and create javascript postback to handle the events.
Alternatively, use Razor...

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I ended up doing the answer I gave.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up embarking on an exercise to programatically create HTML server-side based on inspecting existing asp:DropDownList controls, similar to the output shown at https://jsfiddle.net/hodtfkys/3/.

```
<div class='ui icon selection dropdown'>
  <input name='DropDownListCategoryClone' type='hidden'> <i class='dropdown icon'></i>
  <div class='default text'>
    Male
  </div>
  <div class='menu'>
    <div class='item' data-text='Male' data-value='male'>
      <img class='ui image' src='http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/icons8/ios7/512/Users-User-Male-icon.png' style='width:20px;'> Male
    </div>
    <div class='item' data-text='Female' data-value='female'>
      <img class='ui image' src='http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/icons8/ios7/512/Users-User-Female-icon.png' style='width:20px;'> Female
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```